# Play Framework 2.5 で複数DB接続

Tags: java, playframework

スタックオーバーフローの利用が初めてのものです。
やり取りなどで、ぎこちない部分が多々あるかと思いますが、
どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

仕事でPlay Framework 2.5の利用を検討しております。
公式のドキュメントを見ながら設定を進めておりますが、
複数DB接続の箇所で手詰まりとなっております。

コードはgithubにアップロードしております。
https://github.com/junichimura/play2.5_multiple_database_connection
(動作させるためには、事前に公式より、activator最新版をダウンロードしておく必要があります。)

もちろんgithubのファイルをダウンロードしたくない方がいらっしゃれば、Web上でコードを開示させていただきます。

また、現在発生しているエラーは以下のようなものです。

```
[error] application -

! @70c4075ao - Internal server error, for (GET) [/second/set/sample] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The type [class models.second.SampleTable2] is not a registered entity? If you don't explicitly list the entity classes to use Ebean will search for them in the classpath. If the entity is in a Jar check the ebean.search.jars property in ebean.properties file or check ServerConfig.addJar().]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The type [class models.second.SampleTable2] is not a registered entity? If you don't explicitly list the entity classes to use Ebean will search for them in the classpath. If the entity is in a Jar check the ebean.search.jars property in ebean.properties file or check ServerConfig.addJar().
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:21)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:18)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The type [class models.second.SampleTable2] is not a registered entity? If you don't explicitly list the entity classes to use Ebean will search for them in the classpath. If the entity is in a Jar check the ebean.search.jars property in ebean.properties file or check ServerConfig.addJar().
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.createRequest(DefaultPersister.java:1189)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:208)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.save(DefaultPersister.java:199)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1461)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1454)
        at com.avaje.ebean.Model.save(Model.java:208)
        at controllers.CheckFind.setS2(CheckFind.java:40)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:167)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:167)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
```

なお、該当するSampleTable2クラスには、@Entity アノテーションを付加している状態です。

application.confでの設定は、以下の通りです。

```
db {
  default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/skysea?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
  default.username=skysea
  default.password="skysea"

  second.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  second.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/skysea2?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
  second.username=skysea
  second.password="skysea"

  # You can turn on SQL logging for any datasource
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Highlights25#Logging-SQL-statements
  #default.logSql=true
}

ebean {
  default = ["models.first.*"]
  second = ["models.second.*"]
}
```

知見をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、お力を貸していただければ幸いです。
どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決いたしました。

結論から申し上げますと、Play FrameworkとEbeanのドキュメントには特に役立つ記載はありませんでした。
日本語のドキュメントが全くないため、とても苦戦しました。
同様のことでお困りの方が今後いらっしゃるかもしれませんので、
解決方法を簡単にご紹介しておきます。
（詳しい内容は、質問本文中のgithubへのリンクからソースコードをご覧ください。）

解決方法としては、application.confに接続先DB情報を記載します。

**application.conf**

```
db {
  first.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  first.url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.155/skysea?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
  first.username=skysea
  first.password="skysea"

  second.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  second.url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.155/skysea2?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
  second.username=skysea
  second.password="skysea"

}

ebean {
  first = ["models.first.*"]
  second = ["models.second.*"]
}

play.ebean.defaultDatasource = "ebean.first"
```

com.avaje.ebean.Modelを継承するabstructクラスを作成します。
この際、接続先のDB情報をdbメソッドで定義します。
例)

```
package models.first;

import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServer;
import com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Model extends com.avaje.ebean.Model {

    // application.conf に記載のサーバを指定する。
    public static final String server = "second";

    public static EbeanServer db() {
        return Ebean.getServer(server);
    }

    public void markAsDirty() {
        db().markAsDirty(this);
    }

    public void markPropertyUnset(String propertyName) {
        ((EntityBean) this)._ebean_getIntercept().setPropertyLoaded(propertyName, false);
    }

    public void save() {
        db().save(this);
    }

    public void update() {
        db().update(this);
    }

    public void insert() {
        db().insert(this);
    }

    public boolean delete() {
        return db().delete(this);
    }

    public void update(String server) {
        db(server).update(this);
    }

    public void insert(String server) {
        db(server).insert(this);
    }

    public boolean delete(String server) {
        return db(server).delete(this);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        db().refresh(this);
    }

}
```

モデルを作成する際、保存先のDBを設定しているcom.avaje.ebean.Modelの継承クラスをスパークラスとしてextendsします。

```
package models.first;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class SampleTable1 extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer sampleTable1Id;

    public String sampleTable1Value;

    public static Find<Integer, SampleTable1> find = new Find<Integer, SampleTable1>(Model.server, SampleTable1.class){};

}
```

あとは使うだけです。

```
package controllers;

import java.util.List;

import models.first.SampleTable1;
import models.second.SampleTable2;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class CheckFind extends Controller {

    public Result setS1(String str){

        SampleTable1 s = new SampleTable1();
        s.sampleTable1Value = str;
        s.save();

        return getS1(String.format("[Info] (%s) save success.\n\n", str));
    }

    public Result getS1(String message){
        List<SampleTable1> sList = SampleTable1.find.where().findList();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(message);
        if(sList.size() == 0){
            sb.append("table is empty...");
        }

        for(SampleTable1 s : sList){
            sb.append(String.format("id: %3d (%s)\n", s.sampleTable1Id, s.sampleTable1Value));
        }

        return ok(sb.toString());
    }

    public Result updateS1(int id, String updStr){
        SampleTable1 s = SampleTable1.find.byId(id);

        String before = s.sampleTable1Value;
        s.sampleTable1Value = updStr;
        s.save();

        return getS1(String.format("[Info] (id: %s) %s -> %s\n", s.sampleTable1Id, before, s.sampleTable1Value));
    }

}
```

以上です。